# Number of ordered pairs (a,x) satisfying the equation $\sec^2(a+2)x+a^2-1=0$ where $-\pi<x<\pi$

Tags: trigonometry

So $$\sec^2(a+2)x=1-a^2$$
The equality only holds true when when both sides are equal to 1
$$1-a^2=1$$
$$a=0$$
So $$\sec^2 2x=1$$
$$\cos^22x=cos^2n\pi$$
$$2x=n\pi \pm n\pi$$
Then $x=0$ And 
$$2x=2n\pi$$
$$x=n\pi$$ but since x cannot be $\pi,-\pi$

There is only one value. Answer given is 3. What’s going wrong?

Comment: if $\sec(2x)=-1$ then $\sec^2(2x)=1$ as desired.

Comment: Okay, then I get $x=\pi/2, -\pi/2$. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos^22x=1\iff\sin2x=0,2x=n\pi$$

Alternatively $\cos4x=\cdots=1\implies4x=2n\pi$

$$-2\pi<n\pi<2\pi\implies-2<n<2$$